# Puppetserver unable to locate gems

Tags: puppet, rubygems

I'm trying to use a module which adds an AWS Secrets Manager hiera backend:

https://forge.puppet.com/accenture/hiera_aws_sm

This module requires the **aws-sdk-secretsmanager** gem, which I installed via puppetserver:

```
$ sudo puppetserver gem install aws-sdk-secretsmanager
```

I can also see this gem listed in puppetserver:

```
$ sudo puppetserver gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

<trimmed>
aws-sdk-schemas (1.6.0)
aws-sdk-secretsmanager (1.40.0, 1.39.0)
aws-sdk-securityhub (1.29.0)
<trimmed>
```

The module itself contains the following line to import the gem:

```
require 'aws-sdk-secretsmanager'
```

When I try to run an agent test...

```
$ sudo puppet agent --test
```

... when this module tries to run I get the following error (after commenting out some error handling obfuscation the module added):

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Internal Server Error: org.jruby.exceptions.LoadError: (LoadError) no such file to load -- aws-sdk-secretsmanager
```

I can't work out why the puppetserver jruby instance can't load the gem since it appears in list and have hit a bit of a wall in debugging it.

Comment: The [setup steps](https://forge.puppet.com/accenture/hiera_aws_sm#setup) suggests installing `aws-sdk` which has a runtime dependency on `aws-sdk-resources` and *that* Gem has a runtime dependency on 200+ other aws-sdk-* Gems *including* `aws-sdk-secretsmanager`. Is it possible that because you have bypassed the top-level required Gem that you don't have all of the necessary components? All of that may have been included in the <trimmed> output, but since you don't say that you followed the defined setup procedure; let's start there?

Comment: Yep, `aws-sdk` & `aws-sdk-resources` are there. All dependencies look to have installed fine for purposes of a `gem list` but won't load. i.e. `require 'aws-sdk'` results in the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this issue was because multiple versions of `aws-sdk-secretsmanager` were installed somehow:

```
$ sudo puppetserver gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

<trimmed>
aws-sdk-secretsmanager (1.40.0, 1.39.0)
<trimmed>
```

Running...

```
$ sudo puppetserver gem uninstall aws-sdk-secretsmanager
```

... accepting the prompt to uninstall all installed versions and then running...

```
$ sudo puppetserver gem install aws-sdk-secretsmanager
```

... solved the issue.